# How to prove the following limit with the epsilon proof?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How do I prove the following result without an $\epsilon$-$N$ proof?

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(n!)}{\sqrt[3]{n}} =0$$

Comment: Would you like to share what you have tried/thought of so far?

Comment: How large does $n$ have to be for us to be able to say with certainty that  $|\frac {\sin n!}{\sqrt[3]{n}}- 0| < \epsilon$.  Hint:  $|\sin(n!)| < 1$

Comment: The title of your question contradicts the body of your question. Do you want to use an $\epsilon-N$ proof or use informal logic?

Answer (score 2):

$|\sin(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so you have a bounded function in the numerator, and a decreasing function in the denominator. Explicitly, $$\left| \frac{\sin(n!)}{\sqrt[3]{n}} \right| \leq \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}} \right| \rightarrow 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $|\sin(n!)|\le1$ for all real numbers $n$. So, $\left|\frac{\sin(n!)}{n^{1/3}}\right|\le \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}.$

We need to show that for any positive $\epsilon > 0$, there is a number $N$, such that
if $n > N$ then $\left|\frac{\sin(n!)}{n^{1/3}}\right| < \epsilon$.

Therefore, when $n>N$,

$$\left|\frac{\sin(n!)}{n^{1/3}}\right|\le \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}< \epsilon \implies n > \frac{1}{\epsilon^3}.$$

Now complete the proof.